# Factor multiplied matrix with vector

Tags: matrix, factorization

Say I have a matrix multiplication of the form

$$ B = A \cdot x $$

or

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11} x_1 + a_{12} x_2 + a_{13} x_3 \\
 a_{21} x_1 + a_{22} x_2 + a_{23} x_3 \\
 a_{31} x_1 + a_{32} x_2 + a_{33} x_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
 a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
 a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
 x_1 \\
 x_2 \\
 x_3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Is there a way in Mathematica to factor $B$ in a way where I give it $x$ and it returns $A$?

Comment: @garej I noticed you tried to edit this question to give some *Mathematica* code.  Although I understand that this was done in the best of intentions, I think it would be better to make a request to the OP directly from the comments section.

Comment: You could use `LinearSolve` but the system is underdetermined, hence not uniquely solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. It's simply:

```
Table[Coefficient[B[[i]],#]&/@X,{i,Length[B]}]
```

This will go through each element of `B`, and check the coefficient of each element of `X` for that `B` element, creating a two dimensional array, which is basically `A`.

A short form of this that works for me is:

```
Coefficient[B,#]&/@X
```

Mathematica is smart enough to recognize that it has to apply `Coefficient` on each element of `B`.
For non-symmetric matrixes `Transpose` is needed:

```
mat = {{-1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 4}, {1, -1, 2}}
(Coefficient[mat.X, #] & /@ X) // Transpose
```

> {{-1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 4}, {1, -1, 2}}

Comment: @You forgot to `Transpose` the result, did not you?

Comment: @garej Actually I'm not sure. I'm dealing with symmetric/Hermitian matrices so it doesn't really matter for me. If you're sure, please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: compare `Array[a[##] &, {3, 3}]` and `Coefficient[Array[a[##] &, {3, 3}].{x1, x2, x3}, #] & /@ {x1, x2, x3}`. I would add a sample `a`, say `{{1, 3, -1}, {2, 4, 3}, {3, 5, 2}}` in the question ;))

Answer (score 5):

I would simply do the derivative. It's the shortest way to get the matrix from a linear expression, assuming the vector `X` consists of symbols as written in the question.

First define the matrices and vectors:

```
X = {x1, x2, x3};
A = Array[a, {3, 3}];

B = A.X

(*
==> {x1 a[1, 1] + x2 a[1, 2] + x3 a[1, 3], 
 x1 a[2, 1] + x2 a[2, 2] + x3 a[2, 3], 
 x1 a[3, 1] + x2 a[3, 2] + x3 a[3, 3]}
*)
```

Given these definitions, this is the only thing you need to do:

```
D[B, {X}]

(*
==> {{a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3]}, {a[2, 1], a[2, 2], 
  a[2, 3]}, {a[3, 1], a[3, 2], a[3, 3]}}
*)
```

Comment: tensor derivative - that is very elegant!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `CoefficientArrays[]` function works as well.

Input:

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
X = {x1, x2, x3};
Normal@CoefficientArrays[mat.X, X][[2]]
```

Output:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```